# Joomla: How to create a file inside a component that can be accessed directly?

Tags: joomla

I am trying to override a component. The file structure is like this:

```
templates/mytemplate/html/com_contact/contact/<files>
```

From inside the default_form.php, I want to access another php file. So where do I keep that other file and what changes do I have to make to the component view? I am using Joomla 1.5.15.

Comment: It's offtopic, but why in the world are you using an outdated version of Joomla!??? J1.5 is anyway no longer suported anyway the latest 1.5 version is I think 1.5.26

Answer (score 0):

What type of change?  Is it a change you can make in the template override?

Comment: Yes the change is to be made in the template override. 

For instance, I want to include a page inside an iframe on default_form.php file. Lets say the other page is called myform.php. I want to know how to include this file in iframe src.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can include it as a simple iframe like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) or if you want to include a php file you can use `include` or `require_once` like [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).